# Enforce socket timeout on ActiveMQ from Camel route?

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, activemq-classic, apache-camel

So below I have Camel (via Spring DSL) successfully integrating my beans with ActiveMQ queues:

```
<!-- Note: this code is just a snippet; if you need to see more, please let me know! -->
<camelContext id="my-camel-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq-myinstance:queue:myqueue" />
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" />
            <to uri="activemq-myinstance:queue_failures" />
        </onException>
        <to uri="bean:myBean?method=doCommand" />           
    </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory-myqueue" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${activemq.instance.url}" />
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory-myqueue" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="64" />
    <property name="maximumActive" value="${max.active.consumers}" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory-myqueue" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig-myqueue" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory-myqueue"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${max.active.consumers}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="activemq-myqueue" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig-myqueue"/> 
</bean>
```

I'd like to explicitly enforce a **socket timeout** (on `Socket.read()`) - between Camel and ActiveMQ - of 25 seconds. Thus, when Camel attempts to route a message to/from ActiveMQ, if ActiveMQ takes more than 25 seconds to complete that response, I want the thread to exit gracefully. Obviously, if it's possible to also set up some kind of failover (so that requests that timeout can get replayed at a future time) that is greatly preferred over just losing the message!

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

**Update**: if Camel/JMS/ActiveMQ doesn't support this out of the box, I don't mind writing my own "`ThreadManager`" that interrupts/stops threads after 25-seconds, but I'm not sure what interface/classes to implement/extend, and to subsequently wire into my Spring beans.

Comment: Perhaps if I set an `expiryTimeout` on my `PooledConnectionFactory`?

Answer (score 1):

By default Camel activemq request times out after 20 seconds.

For send timeouts there is a sendTimeout property on org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.
Also check the requesttimeout option for JMSConfiguraiton.

For failover you can set the failover transport in the broker url.

Comment: Thanks @user-soma (+1) - what's the name of the 20-second ActiveMQ timeout? And what's the difference between this timeout and the "send timeout" that you mentioned? Thanks again!

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys - My understanding is that camel jms request timeout and ActiveMQConnectionFactory sendtimeout serve the same purpose, ie., to inform the producer of timeout.
Message expiry indicates the time relevancy of a message. This gives hint to the broker not to send expired messages to the consumer. timeToLive on jmsconfiguration indicates this.

Answer (score 1):

just set the `timeout` property on your brokerURL

```
failover:(tcp\://localhost\:61616)?timeout=25000
```

this will propagate an error back to your producer so you can handle it instead of having it just blocking the thread forever...